# How to delete the shortcut button in the lower right corner in beamer?

Tags: beamer

I'm wondering is there any method to delete the button line in the lower right corner as show in the picture (above the page number). Thank you[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine the `navigation symbols` template:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```